# Creating a zipped folder at the click of a button

Tags: php, unix

I have a folder with files, and at the click of a button from an application, I would like to create a zipped version of the folder. I understand that it's possible to create a tar.gz version on a UNIX system by passing in the command exec(`tar -cvf foldername destination_filename`).

Question: Is it possible to create a zipped file on a UNIX system? If it is possible, what's the logic/command behind it?

Comment: Have you looked at the ZipArchive extension in the PHP manual? - http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Comment: @MarkBaker I never even knew about its existence; thanks for that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most *nix systems will support the following commnad:

```
zip -r destination_filename.zip foldername
```

Answer (score 1):

Use php zip extension? http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php
And i guess you'll find useful classes from phpclasses too: http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=zip&x=0&y=0&go_search=1

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `-z` option to `tar` to have it also zip the file:

```
tar -czf foo.tar.gz foo/
```

Make sure you are in a place that the webserver has write privileges.  For example, you may need chdir into the parent folder of the folder you wish to zip, and then get a temp file name in `/tmp`, and then create the command to zip to that temp file name.

It sounds like you have the rest figured out!

http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html

Comment: if I save it in the /tmp folder, won't it get deleted once the scrip finishes running, just as in uploaded files? Thanks